# Restrict access to a webpage with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to restrict access to a specific webpage such as http://www.example.com/subpage with jQuery?
I know there are many other feasible ways to accomplish that via PHP and `.htaccess` but in our case, we don't have access to the `.htaccess` file. However jQuery is installed.

I was thinking to try to read the `window.location.href` and add a hash to the URL. But I am not sure if this can be exposed if a user view the source code of the page in question.

Comment: JavaScript is always visible at the client side, so I would definitely reconsider using PHP! This is something that really has to be done server-side.

Comment: This can be done via `PHP` (without `.htaccess`). I can provide details if you are open to this option

Comment: Thank you James. We don't have PHP on this server. Is there a way we can read the href and add a password input that users have to fill in predefined password. if it is correct the user will be taken to the page in question. It is not a big deal with view source code...

Comment: @Rolnado: Thank you so much. The server is not using PHP at all. it is on .net and we don't have access to the FTP as such to manipulate the pages.

Comment: This may be a bit too crazy: You could load parts of the page with Ajax, as tandu suggests it, but store them *encrypted* on the server. On the client side, let the user type in the password and use a JavaScript implementation of an crypto algorithm to decrypt the received data.

Comment: I have provided my answer before I saw that you are using ASP. ASP has server-side includes. But I do not know if defined constants are visible within those includes. If it is, then my method should still work.

Comment: Felix, great idea, why don't you post that as an answer? I would vote for it. I don't think it's too crazy, in fact it'd be pretty easy to automate with [SJCL](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) and Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented Felix Kling's idea and wrote a node.js script to automate the process. Basically it takes your (original) HTML page and a password as input, and generates an HTML page that embeds an encrypted copy of the original one. When you browse to this generated HTML page, it prompts you for a password to unlock it.

This is just a proof of concept, so there's a lot you would have to do to make this production-ready. You'd definitely want some friendly error messages if you put in the wrong password, for example. And it would probably be really irritating to enter the password every time you move between pages on the site, so you might consider saving the password in a cookie or passing it along in the URL every time. Also, as currently designed you can only have one password that everyone shares. This is a solvable problem, just re-encrypt the main key once for each unique username/password pair and put all that data right in the web page.

Anyway, [here's a demo](http://www.joecheng.com/resume/encrypted.html) (the password is "ItWorks"). I put the code for the tool [on GitHub](http://github.com/jcheng5/dumbcrypt).

There are lots of reasons why this approach is not particularly secure, but if you really cared about security you'd pony up for web hosting with .htaccess and script support, right? :)

Comment: Thank you so much Joe. That would work fine for this task. I will do some other modifications to suit the server settings.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting access on the client side is risky and there are probably many ways to get around it.  You may not have access with .htaccess, but can't you use php?

No warranty for this idea:

You need to use javascript to load the parts of the page you would not otherwise display via ajax.  If you don't, the parts of the page you want to prevent the user from seeing can easily be seen if they disable javascript.  You can of course do that ajax load conditionally based on whatever data the page needs to have to signal that the user is authentic, but this can be spoofed very easily.  At this point, you have to talk to the server anyway, so why not just restrict access there?

If you're only worried about keeping dumb (i.e. non-developer) users out the above will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment:

You could load parts of the page with Ajax, as [@tandu suggests it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358550/restrict-access-to-a-webpage-with-jquery/7358604#7358604), but store them encrypted on the server.

On the client side, let the user type in the password and use a JavaScript implementation of the crypto algorithm you used to decrypt the received data. Just make sure you use some well tested implementation and don't create one on your own!

This also might not be perfectly secure, but there are two advantages:

- The password is not contained in the source code (plain or obscured).
- Direct access the parts loaded via Ajax don't reveal any information (they are encrypted).

The disadvantages are:

- There is some pre-processing involved, to encrypt the pages (parts) (which could be automated, see @Joe Cheng's comment to your question).
- Client has to perform decryption (which might have impact on the performance).

In addition, you have to determine whether the decryption was successful or not.

Comment: I'm sorry to take your idea and submit my own answer--not sure if that is a Stack Overflow faux pas (if not, maybe it should be). I had more to say than fit in a comment though, hope you don't mind. I upvoted your answer at least!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you can't.

Slightly longer answer: All your javascript is sent to the user, to see. You can't hide any of your source code from them. With PHP/htaccess, all of your source code is hidden, so they can't tell how you process the data.

Comment: Thank you so much but we cannot use php nor .htaccess. Only javascript can be used.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck. There's nothing you can do in JS to secure it. You can make it "a little bit of a mild inconvenience", but that's about it.

Comment: @digitup Just seen you're running .NET - you can definitely use .NET for it. Also, assuming you're running IIS, if you can edit web.config you can set up the IIS equivalent of htpasswd pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you so much but I have no access to the FTP at all. Only editing the page is allowed where we can add some JS in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Since lots of people are already saying no. I might as well post this answer using PHP.

If those files are only meant to be included, then you can use `define()` in your including file. You included files will then check for the defined constant and exit immediately if not found. This way, you can be sure that the rest of the code will only be interpreted within an include.

If we are simply talking about user access levels (i.e. these files may be called via HTTP but restricted within users, then you have to use `sessions` for that and set the appropriate access level for the user which every page will check and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

To do this in JavaScript (with a bit of jQuery as you mentioned that you're using it), you can simply check the value of a `password` input whenever you need to, and compare it with a predefined password.

**Disclaimer** I would never, ever recommend this. I'm only even posting an answer because you've specifically said that it doesn't matter if users can see the source.

Having said that, assume some HTML as follows:

```
<input type="password" id="pass"> 
<input type="button" id="b" value="Login">
<span id="err"></span>
```

You can use some JS similar to this:

```
$("#b").click(function() {
    var password = "password";
    if($("#pass").val() !== password) {
        $("#err").text("Incorrect password");
    }
    else {
        $("#err").text("Password correct! Do whatever you need to do here.");   
    }
});
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LpdQm/1/) (also notice how easy it is to see the password!).

Comment: Thanks again James but how can we load this form before the page in question displays. The form in this case must be loaded before the content of the page. Can we have the script in the header, hide the div that has the content and make it visible if the password matches? I am aware this is not the best solution.

Comment: Have this in it's own page, then use `window.location` in the `else` block to send the user to the correct page.